# postgresql with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, synchronization, sql-server-2000

I have two databases servers one on SQL Server 2000, second on PostgreSQL on different server. I want to link them. I create duplicate table on the PostgreSQL. Now I want, when new value appeared in SQL Server duplicate them to PostgreSQL. How to do that? How can I see the SQL Server on PostgreSQL? Or must I create an application which will send message from SQL Server to PostgreSQL?

Comment: OK, updated your post accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a description on how to set up master/slave replication between SQL Server and Postgres (i.e. SQL Server=master updates to Postgres):

http://blog.hagander.net/archives/103-Replicating-from-MS-SQL-Server-to-PostgreSQL.html

Looks like your scenario.